# How is CIAdditionCompositing different from componentAdd?

Tags: ios, core-image, compositing

Core Image offers two ways to add two images: 
[CIAdditionCompositing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAdditionCompositing) and [componentAdd](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciblendkernel/2867384-componentadd). I could use either to sum up the pixel values in two images. Are they different except for the latter being supported only on iOS 11?

For example, does one do the addition in linear space while the other in gamma space?